# C# making a tab, adding controls to the tab, and then having multiple tabs of that type

Tags: c#, controls, tabs, addition

```
TabPage newpage = new TabPage();
Tabs.TabPages.Add(newpage);
newpage.Controls.Add(this.tableLayoutPanel41);
newpage.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(4, 26);
newpage.Name = "AddMaintAgreement" + offset;
newpage.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(736, 523);
newpage.TabIndex = 10;
newpage.Text = "Add Maintenance Agreement";
newpage.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
offset++;
```

Basically thats what i have at the moment, I added the offset in there because i thought it might affect my problem.

Basically, this code here works okay for adding one "addmaintagreement" tab. After that only the latest tab has any controls on it!

Basically I'm stumped. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I think short example should stay here:

```
        TextBox tmpLog = new TextBox(); // create new control of textbox type
        tmpLog.Text = "some text here";

        TabPage tb = new TabPage("my brand new tab"); //create tab
        tabControl.TabPages.Add(tb); // add tab to existed TabControl
        tb.Controls.Add(tmpLog); // add textBox to new tab

        tabControl.SelectedTab = tb;     // activate tab
```

Answer (score 1):

Derive from TabPage and add the controls you want in that derived class. Then use your derived class instead of TabPage.

Answer (score 0):

Controls can only be parented to one control, but it looks like you are trying to parent your `tableLayoutPanel41` in every `TabPage` instance. You need to create new copies of the controls for each instance of the tab. There are various ways to fix this.

1. Programmatically create your tab page and its contents multiple times.
2. Have the contents of your `TabPage` implemented as a user control that you dock fill on a tab page. Then recreate one of those for each page duplicate your require.
3. Create a class derived from `TabPage` that implements your tab page and create new instances of that for each use.